# How do I get this div to height 100%? (flexbox on container)

Tags: html, css, height, flexbox

I have a problem with a `div` that I can't get to `height:100%`, I have tried to use `!important` but that didn't help. I guess it has some thing to do with my flexbox on my container `.row`?

It is the `div` with the class `the-list I want to get to 100%.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e488j5sp/

HTML:

```
<div class="row equal-height"> <!-- START BS ROW -->
    <div class="col-md-1"> <!-- START BS COL-MD-1 -->
    </div> <!-- END BS COL-MD-1 -->
    <div class="col-md-3 zeropadding-right"> <!-- START BS COL-MD-4 -->
        <div class="singlepage-list-style"> <!-- START SINGLEPAGE-LIST-STYLE -->
            <div class="list-header"> <!-- START LISTE-HEADER -->
                <h1>Quick info</h1>
            </div> <!-- END LIST-HEADER -->
            <div class="the-list"> <!-- START THE-LISTE -->
            <img src="http://placehold.it/150x100">
            </div> <!-- END THE-LIST -->
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END BS COLD-MD-4 -->
    <div class="col-md-7 zeropadding-left"> <!-- START BS COL-MD-6 -->
        <div class="singleheader-content-style"> <!-- START SINGLEPAGE-CONTENT-STYLE -->
            <h1>Property description</h1>
            <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150">
        </div> <!-- END SINGLEHEADER-CONTENT-STYLE -->
    </div> <!-- END BS COL-MD-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-1"> <!-- START BS COL-MD-1 -->
    </div> <!-- END BS COL-MD-1 -->
</div> <!-- END BS ROW -->
```

CSS:

```
/***** INFO & CONTENT HEIGHT CONTROLER *****/

.equal-height, .equal-height > div[class*='col-'] {  
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -moz-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      flex:1 0 auto;
  }

.zeropadding-right {
    padding-right:0px;
}

/***** SINGLEHEADER CONTENT AREA STYLING *****/

.singleheader-content-style {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-right: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    padding:20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width:100%;
}

.singleheader-content-style h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin-top:0px; /* Change boostraps default */
    color:#de1b1b;
}

/***** SINGLEHEADER LIST AREA STYLING *****/

.singlepage-list-style {
    background-color:#fff;
    border-left: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    padding:20px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    width:100%;
    font-size:16px;
}

.singlepage-list-style ul li {
    list-style-type:none;
}

.singlepage-list-style ul {
    padding-left:20px;
}

.the-list {
    border-right: 1px solid #9c9c9c;
    width:100%;
}

.list-header {
    width:100%;
}

.list-header h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    margin-top:0px; /* Change boostraps default */
    color:#de1b1b;
}
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Some people have suggested that to solve this issue I need to set `height:100%` to all parent element. So I have tried to do that. But the problem is that when I do so the div elements with the classes `singlepage-list-style` and `singleheader-content-style` end up with different heights (307px and 267px). This was the purpose of "flex" in the `equal-height` class, to give those two elements the same height (and at the same time adjust height to its content), in this case both should end up with the height 307px. And that does no longer work when `height:100%` is added to all parent elements. For more details see the conversations in the comments for the answers below. Here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5s9mmdtx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you make sure that all parent tags are with `height: 100%` attribute or you'll end up filling only 100% of the current tag.

You can use `height: 100vh` instead, using your body height as a max height.

> Using 100vh instead means that the p tag will be 100% height of the body regardless of the div height.

You can see more detailed information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16837667/3758439).

Comment: Hi, I can't get it to work. If I add 100% height to the parent element, the flexbox loses its function and the columns end up at different heights: https://jsfiddle.net/aLjj4fyz/

Comment: Also see comments on the answer above yours  :)